# How to simulate click to image (by coordinates)

Tags: c#, puppeteer

Sorry for my bad english. I have an image on page? so I have a coordinates of image for clicking. And i need to simulate click to point of image by coordinates. How can I do it in PuppeteerSharp?

I need something like:

```
_page.Mouse.ClickAsync(x, y);
```

For example? I have a coordinates of image (150, 86), and I need to click to this point on image.

How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What actually a problem? `PuppeteerSharp` contain `IMouse` interface that provides `clickAsync`

[Reference](http://www.puppeteersharp.com/api/PuppeteerSharp.Input.IMouse.html)

Code should be like

```js
var imageSelector = "your-image-selector";
var imageHandle = await page.WaitForSelectorAsync(imageSelector);
var imageBoundingBox = await imageHandle.BoundingBoxAsync();

var x = imageBoundingBox.X + 150; 
var y = imageBoundingBox.Y + 86;  

await page.Mouse.ClickAsync(x, y);
```